# Iterate the loop in angular js (ng-repeat)

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-repeat

This is my `json` object. How do I loop through test and testing values inside `data_options->"key"->options` and show them in checkbox values?

```
    {
    "data": {
        "0": {
            "id": 2,
            "survey_id": 14,
            "question": "What's here?",
            "question_type": 2,
            "created_at": "2016-07-15 18:29:05",
            "updated_at": "2016-07-15 18:29:05",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "type": "checkbox",
            "ques_options_id": 2,
            "key": "pqr",
            "value": "PQR",
            "survey_user_id": 39
        },
        "1": {
            "id": 9,
            "survey_id": 14,
            "question": "Whats demo? ",
            "question_type": 4,
            "created_at": "2016-07-15 18:29:05",
            "updated_at": "2016-07-15 18:29:05",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "type": "dropdown",
            "ques_options_id": 9,
            "key": "checking",
            "value": "Checking",
            "survey_user_id": 39
        },
        "2": {
            "id": 1,
            "survey_id": 14,
            "question": "What's in your mind?",
            "question_type": 1,
            "created_at": "2016-07-15 18:29:05",
            "updated_at": "2016-07-15 18:29:05",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "type": "textarea",
            "ques_options_id": 1,
            "key": "abc",
            "value": "ABC",
            "survey_user_id": 39
        },
        "3": {
            "id": 8,
            "survey_id": 14,
            "question": "Whats abc here?",
            "question_type": 3,
            "created_at": "2016-07-15 18:29:05",
            "updated_at": "2016-07-15 18:29:05",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "type": "radio",
            "ques_options_id": 8,
            "key": "abcde",
            "value": "ABCDEF",
            "survey_user_id": 39
        },
        "4": {
            "id": 10,
            "survey_id": 14,
            "question": "Testing here?",
            "question_type": 2,
            "created_at": "2016-07-15 18:29:05",
            "updated_at": "2016-07-15 18:29:05",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "type": "checkbox",
            "ques_options_id": 10,
            "key": "test",
            "value": "Test",
            "survey_user_id": 39
        },
        "5": {
            "id": 10,
            "survey_id": 14,
            "question": "Testing here?",
            "question_type": 2,
            "created_at": "2016-07-15 18:29:05",
            "updated_at": "2016-07-15 18:29:05",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "type": "checkbox",
            "ques_options_id": 10,
            "key": "Testing",
            "value": "Testing",
            "survey_user_id": 39
        },
        "data_option": {
            "1": {
                "options": {
                    "0": {
                        "abc": "ABC"
                    }
                },
                "question": "What's in your mind?",
                "type": "textarea"
            },
            "2": {
                "options": {
                    "0": {
                        "pqr": "PQR"
                    }
                },
                "question": "What's here?",
                "type": "checkbox"
            },
            "8": {
                "options": {
                    "0": {
                        "abcde": "ABCDEF"
                    }
                },
                "question": "Whats abc here?",
                "type": "radio"
            },
            "9": {
                "options": {
                    "0": {
                        "checking": "Checking"
                    }
                },
                "question": "Whats demo? ",
                "type": "dropdown"
            },
            "10": {
                "options": {
                    "0": {
                        "test": "Test"
                    },
                    "1": {
                        "Testing": "Testing"
                    }
                },
                "question": "Testing here?",
                "type": "checkbox"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try to use ng-if inside ng-repeat

Answer (score 0):

First convert object to array and then you can use ng-repeat on array as below:

```
var myObj = {
    0: {
        "id": 1,
        "survey_id": 12
       },
    1: {
        "id": 2,
        "survey_id": 14
       },
};

var array = $.map(myObj, function(value, index) {
    return [value];
});
```

Comment: how do i show Test as dropdown value and key test as dropdown value "10": { "options": { "0": { "test": "Test" }, "1": { "Testing": "Testing" } }, "question": "Testing here?", "type": "checkbox" }

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in view,

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ListCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="patient in data.data.data_option ">
       <div ng-repeat="detail in patient.options ">        
         <input type="checkbox">
         <span class="done-{{todo.done}}">{{detail}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

[`Working Application`](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/7cLyzyLa/2/)

Comment: how do i show Test as dropdown value and key test as dropdown value  "10": {
                "options": {
                    "0": {
                        "test": "Test"
                    },
                    "1": {
                        "Testing": "Testing"
                    }
                },
                "question": "Testing here?",
                "type": "checkbox"
            }

Comment: @Deepa check the application , it displays